# Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object at Function.use

Tags: node.js, recaptcha

Code for contact.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer= require('nodemailer');
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();

    // Basic usage
    dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('contact', { title: 'Contact' });
});


  router.post('/send', function(req, res, next) {
          verifyRecaptcha(req.body["g-recaptcha-response"], function(success) {
                  if (success) {
                          res.end("Success!");
                          // TODO: do registration using params in req.body
                          var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                            service: 'Gmail',
                            auth: {
                              user : 'email@gmail.com',
                              pass : 'pass'
                            }
                          });
                          var mailOptions = {
                          from: 'Thiyagaraj <email@gmail.com>',
                          to : 'email@gmail.com',
                          subject : now +req.body.from ,
                          text : 'Order placed '

                          };
                          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                            if(error){
                              console.log(error);
                              res.redirect('/');
                            }else{
                              console.log('message sent');
                              res.redirect('/');
                            }
                          });
                  } else {
                          res.end("Captcha failed, sorry.");
                          // TODO: take them back to the previous page
                          res.render('about', { title: 'About' });
                  }
          });
  });

/*
});

module.exports = router;
*/
```

this is for recaptcha verification ... 
is there any special dependency required ?
Or is there a mistake with the code
...................................
...................................

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last line of your router needs to be uncommented.

```
module.exports = router;
```

This is the code that exposes the router to your app. I'm guessing you have something that is requiring this file somewhere and passing it in to an `app.use`, but this file isn't exporting anything (because it's commented out) so the `app.use` is expecting a function but getting undefined.